# How is the current drawn by a Peltier determined for a given voltage and given Th?

Tags: current-measurement, peltier

I have 12V 20A SMPS for building a cloud chamber.

I have a question about configuring the Peltiers. I don't know how much current a Peltier draws for a given V at given Th (hot side °C)

In my understanding:

[image: TEC1-12710]

For example, a TEC1-12710 supplied with 12V, maintaining Th=25°C, has resistance of 1.08 ohm, so it draws I=(V/R)=11.1A.  To get high Δt(around 55°c) the Peltier should draw 7.5 to 8A at 12V

I don't know how a semiconductor Peltier works at this step:

[image: ∆t graph]

Please correct me if I wrongly understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A peltier appears almost like a resistor. In your case, the resistor will be about 1.1 Ohm. Your question is, if driving it with 12 V is ok: Yes it is fine, and in fact almost the optimum voltage to achieve the lowest possible cold side temperature. The resistance will be also larger for higher current, and the 1.08 Ohm are likely given for a very small current. Even with the same Th, the resistance will rise as you push more current, because the semiconductor parts inside heat up.

Don't worry if the current will be 7 or 9 or 11 A.. You will put in a certain power, and the higher the power, the stronger the heat transfer. To maximize power you can do two things:

1. You have to establish good cooling for the hot side. A lower average temperature reduces resistance and increases power
2. Increase voltage, but 12 V is already plenty for this Peltier.

With good cooling at constant voltage of 12 V, you should reach Delta T of 60 K

Comment: i have question about heat transfer.Lets say, the peltier at 12v (same Th=25°c) having 1.1 ohm runs 
at 10.9A. But how the HEAT TRANSFER is determined,while the10.9A lines doesn't meets 12V in (∆T vs V)graph?

Comment: Those graphs are typical, to show the trend. You can't treat them as accurate for your specific device.

Comment: @KisoreG as I wrote, if you are running at 12 VDC with several Amps, the resistance will be larger than 1.1 Ohm because of severe internal heating. The 1.1 Ohm is a ballpark figure. It is not the Hot side temperature as such, that determines resistance, but it is the junction temperature. And the junction temp depends mostly on current